# Simple HTML Login Form

Tags: java, html, oracle, servlets, jax-rs

I have created a simple HTML login form with some css design, I want to connect it to an Oracle database to match users with, project is JAX-RS Web Service, so I am not sure how to make it check against an oracle database when people are trying to login?

```
<div class="login">
<div class="login-triangle"></div>

<h2 class="login-header">Login</h2>

<form class="login-container">
<p><input type="email" placeholder="Username"></p>
<p><input type="password" placeholder="Password"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Login"></p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to learn server language (php,.net..etc) that connected to the database and processing your logic.

from HTML you cant.

Comment: Can I use Java? with JDBC/ODBC and servlets perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

Indeed, you need a backend language in order to access and make use of a Oracle database. If you are interested in using Java, and are still learning the ways of web programming, you may want to try NetBeans and read a little bit about what you can do with it. You can find more [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/oracle-db.html).